# using break function within the function to stop the further execution of program

Tags: python, dataframe

```
def my_function(df_1) :
         
         df_1 = df_1.filter[['col_1','col_2','col_3']]
         
         # Keeping only those records where col_1 == 'success'
         df_1 = df_1[df_1['col_1'] == 'success']
         
         # Checking if the df_1 shape is 0
         if df_1.shape[0]==0:
             print('No records found')
             break

        #further program
```

I am looking to break the execution of further program if the **if** condition is met.

is this the correct way to do so..? since break only ends the loop, but i want to end the function

Comment: Do you want to stop the function or the program all together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
 if df_1.shape[0]==0:
         print('No records found')
         return
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for further clarification, the answers above are correct, but the `break` statement is used in loops like a `for` loop or `while` loop to end the loop prematurely.

Functions on the other hand end either at the last line or when `return` is called. If no agument is passed to `return`, the function returns `None` by default. (`None` is also returned by default if the `return` statement is not called at all.)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `break` with `return` just using `return` will help you escape the function which will break the further execution of the function.

```
def my_function(df_1) :
     
     df_1 = df_1.filter[['col_1','col_2','col_3']]
     
     # Keeping only those records where col_1 == 'success'
     df_1 = df_1[df_1['col_1'] == 'success']
     
     # Checking if the df_1 shape is 0
     if df_1.shape[0]==0:
         print('No records found')
         return

    #further program
```